# Word document always opening in readonly mode

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, ms-word

I am trying to write some text to word document using c# code. However, whenever I am opening the doc, it is opening in read only mode. below is my code:-

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

namespace WFA1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            
            string textboxText = textBox1.Text.ToString();
            InsertToFile(textboxText);
        }

        void InsertToFile(string inputString) // function to insert string to word doc
        {
            object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
            object readOnly = false;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = app.Documents.Open("C:\\Users\\SS5014874\\Desktop\\JohnH.docx", ref missing, ref readOnly, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);                        
            app.ActiveDocument.Characters.Last.Select();
            app.Selection.Collapse();
            app.Selection.TypeText(inputString.ToString());            
            app.ActiveDocument.Save();
            MessageBox.Show("Inserted");
        }             

        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            
            string comboBoxText = comboBox1.Text.ToString();
            string comboBoxTextExpanded = "";
            if (comboBoxText == "BP")
            {
                comboBoxTextExpanded = "Balance paid";
            }
            else
            {
                if (comboBoxText == "FA")
                {
                    comboBoxTextExpanded = "Financial advisor";
                }                
            }

            InsertToFile(comboBoxTextExpanded);               
        }              

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string searchKeyword = textBox2.Text.ToString();
            searchText(searchKeyword);
        }

        void searchText(string txt) // function to search string and delete line
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();                       
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = app.Documents.Open("C:\\Users\\SS5014874\\Desktop\\JohnH.docx");
            object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
            doc.Content.Find.ClearFormatting();
            object keyword = txt.ToString();            
            var range = doc.Content;
            if (range.Find.Execute(ref keyword, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, 
                ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing))            
            {                                
                range.Expand(WdUnits.wdParagraph);
                range.Delete();
                MessageBox.Show("removed para");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Not found");
            }
            //doc.Close(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
            //app.Quit(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);            
        }        


    }
}
```

Could you please help me on this ? I am finding the exception at line `app.ActiveDocument.Save();`

Comment: Did u try with a different document? Make sure the document itself doesn't have the read only check in the file properties box

Comment: @slayernoah- Yes, I tried with new document also, however, those are also opening in read only mode. Once the code is run for the first time, afterwards, the document is becoming read only. for the first time it works.

Comment: try using `app.ActiveDocument.Close();` after saving it

Comment: before you try it, you would have to go to task manager and end all `winword.exe` processes since the previous documents were not closed. and also use `app.Quit();` after closing the document

Comment: did this help you?

Answer (score 1):

Add `app.ActiveDocument.Close();` and `app.ActiveDocument.Quit();` after `app.ActiveDocument.Save();`

Updated code:

```
    void InsertToFile(string inputString) // function to insert string to word doc
    {
        object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        object readOnly = false;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = app.Documents.Open("C:\\Users\\SS5014874\\Desktop\\JohnH.docx", ref missing, ref readOnly, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);                        
        app.ActiveDocument.Characters.Last.Select();
        app.Selection.Collapse();
        app.Selection.TypeText(inputString.ToString());            
        app.ActiveDocument.Save();
        app.ActiveDocument.Close();
        app.Quit();
        MessageBox.Show("Inserted");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
app.ActiveDocument.Close(WdSaveOptions.wdSaveChanges);
```